# How to choose a specific FileSystem to work on?

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem

I've an EC2 instance running, here's version:

```
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2017.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2017.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2017.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03
```

but I keep getting `No space left on device` on this instance, when I do `df -H`, I got following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         65G   87k   65G   1% /dev
tmpfs            65G     0   65G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       11G   11G     0 100% /
/dev/xvdb1      5.4G  119M  5.3G   3% /emr
/dev/xvdb2      545G   15G  530G   3% /mnt
/dev/xvdc       550G  506M  549G   1% /mnt1
/dev/xvdd       550G  506M  549G   1% /mnt2
/dev/xvde       550G  506M  549G   1% /mnt3
```

Apparently my /dev/xvda1 is full at 100%, so my question is how can I choose which FileSystem my applications to work on?
In my case, I only want to apps to work in /dev/xvdb1, /dev/xvdb2, /dev/xvdc, /dev/xvdd and /dev/xvde, where can I have control over that?
Or is it even possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with EC2 or the /dev/xvd... devices, what are they? At any rate, check where your /home is and consider putting it on another device with some more free space, /etc/fstab is usually helpful but whatever EC2 is might interfere?

Comment: I did `echo $HOME` and got this `/home/hadoop`, how can I check which device is it mounted on? And how can I put it on another device? Thanks!

Comment: `df` will tell you where a file is, but from your df output it looks like /dev/xvda1. Normally programs get installed somewhere in root (`/`) and data & config files go in /home (which can be separate from /). A line in fstab should do it, something like `<device> /home <fstype> <options>` but search to find out

Comment: @FisherCoder did you find the answer? I'm having the same question.